# Drawing a circle in iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Trying to draw circles (well pinpoints as stars) onto a black background. Searched through Stack but none of the other solutions are working.

Trying to use;

```
CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(100, 100, 5, 5));
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 0, 1.0);
```

The circles are not appearing and the following error message is appearing in the log:

> <Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0.
>   This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is
>   using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall
>   degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a
>   courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an
>   upcoming update.

Any help to solve this (even completely different/easier way to achieve my goal) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Drawing a circle in xcode"...excuse my ignorance, but, is xcode a drawing tool?

Comment: can you try drawing some other things linke line to check weather the code is fine

Comment: xcode is not a drawing tool, however using some code it can "draw" on the screen.

Comment: I cannot get other shapes to work either at this time with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to draw a circle on screen using CAShapeLayer is the simplest method.

```
 CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
 circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)].CGPath;
 circle.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

 [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

This code create a CAShapeLayer and then sets the path of it be an oval in a CGRect you define. This one draws a 100x100 circle on the top left side of the screen. Then you add the layer to any other layer. So for a basic implementation just add it the the layer of the UIView you are working with. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in a recent project and worked fine:

```
-(UIView *)circleWithColor:(UIColor *)color radius:(int)radius {
  UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)];
  circle.backgroundColor = color;
  circle.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
  circle.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  return circle;
}
```

and then add to current view (for example in a UIViewController subclass):

```
  UIView *instoreImageDot=[self circleWithColor:[UIColor redColor] radius:4];
  [self.view addSubview:instoreImageDot];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I couldn't get this to work (possibly due to me only being new to iOS).

Comment: no problem if any questions let me know. It's returning a view so you'd just need to add that to your view.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get a circle

```
    UIView * circle = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 10)];
    circle.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    circle.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.width/2.0;
    circle.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview: circle];
```

Comment: This code looks concise and favourable, however it appeared to not do anything.